# Syntax error trying to rewrite expression using rules

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement, syntax, rule

I want to use Mathematica to calculate derivatives of some long, complicated expressions. I have an integral with integrand $I_*$ which is a functional that depends on $h(x,t)$ and $\phi(x,t)$. The first thing I need to do though is to rewrite the functional in terms of $h,\psi$ where $\psi = h \phi$. I wrote the following couple lines in Mathematica:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
mag[vec_] := Sqrt[vec . vec] 
SubStar[I] = \[Gamma] (1 + mag[Grad[h[x, t], {x}]]^2) + 
       f[h[x, t], \[Phi][x, t]] + 
       h[x, t] g[\[Phi][x, t]] + \[Sigma]/
       2 h[x, t] mag[Grad[\[Phi][x, t], {x}]]^2
\[Psi]sub = {\[Phi][x, t] -> \[Psi][x, t]/h[x, t], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] -> D[\[Psi][x, t]/h[x, t], x], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] -> D[\[Psi][x, t]/h[x, t], {x, 2}]}

\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(**\)]\) = SubStar[I] /. \[Psi]sub
```

In the first line, I define a magnitude function which calculates the magnitude of a vector. The second line is where I define the integrand I am interested in, here called $I_*$. I then define replacement rules for $\phi, \phi_x, \phi_{xx}$ as these are the derivatives that appear. The final line is where I try to create a new variable, called $I_{**}$, which is strictly written in terms of $h,\psi$. However, I am getting a syntax error that says "Incomplete expression; more input is needed. What does this mean? What is the issue?

What seems even stranger to me is the fact that if I don't bother defining $I_*$ or $\psi sub$ as variables and just try to accomplish all of this in one step, then the code executes with no problem. As in:

```
int = \[Gamma] (1 + mag[Grad[h[x, t], {x}]]^2) + 
f[h[x, t], \[Phi][x, t]] + 
h[x, t] g[\[Phi][x, t]] + \[Sigma]/
2 h[x, t] mag[Grad[\[Phi][x, t], {x}]]^2 /. {\[Phi][x, 
t] -> \[Psi][x, t]/h[x, t], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] -> D[\[Psi][x, t]/h[x, t], x], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] -> D[\[Psi][x, t]/h[x, t], {x, 
2}]}
```

So what am I doing wrong in the first case? What is the actual syntax error?

Comment: It looks like it's not possible to use two `*` in the subscript. You'll need to use a different name for the variable

Comment: That's the only error? How can you tell that?

Answer (score 1):

It is not good to use `I` as a variable, also with stars. By evaluating your code you can make sure that in some cases (at least) Mma understands it as the imaginary unit with star.
I suggest to write `I1`istead of I with one star and `I2` instead of that with two ones. Your code takes the form:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
mag[vec_] := Sqrt[vec . vec] 
I1 = γ (1 + mag[Grad[h[x, t], {x}]]^2) + 
         f[h[x, t], ϕ[x, t]] + 
         h[x, t] g[ϕ[x, t]] + σ/
           2 h[x, t] mag[Grad[ϕ[x, t], {x}]]^2
ψsub = {ϕ[x, t] -> ψ[x, t]/h[x, t], 
  
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ϕ\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] -> D[ψ[x, t]/h[x, t], x], 
  
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ϕ\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] -> D[ψ[x, t]/h[x, t], {x, 2}]}

I2 = I1 /. ψsub
```

This at least, successfully evaluates. Try it. If it is what you expected is up to you to deside.

**Concerning your first question**: rewrite `I1` in terms of ψ and h. Try this:

```
I1 /. ϕ -> (ψ[#1, #2]/h[#1, #2] &) // Simplify

(*  f[h[x, t], ψ[x, t]/h[x, t]] + 
 g[ψ[x, t]/h[x, t]] h[x, t] + γ (1 + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(h\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t]^2) + (σ (ψ[x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(h\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t] - h[x, t] 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(ψ\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, t])^2)/(2 h[x, t]^3) *)
```

I did not understand the second question. Hope this helps. Have fun!